# asp .net core redirect inside midleware

Tags: asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I want to create a page allowing to create the database and initialize the default data of an application for each new deployment. for that I create a middleware which checks if it is possible to connect to the database. in the event that it is not possible to connect to the database (which means that the database does not yet exist), the middleware redirects to an action of the application responsible for collecting the default data and proceed with the creation of the database.
However, in the middleware the redirect does not work despite all attempts except for a redirect to an external site such as google.com.
I use **asp.net core 2.2** and **entityframework core**

MissingDatabaseMiddleware.cs

```
public class MissingDatabaseMiddleware
    {
        private readonly RequestDelegate _next;
        private readonly string _missingTenantUrl;

        public MissingDatabaseMiddleware(RequestDelegate next, string missingTenantUrl)
        {
            _next = next;
            _missingTenantUrl = missingTenantUrl;
        }
        public async Task Invoke(HttpContext httpContext, MydbContext context)
        {
            if (!context.Database.CanConnect())
            {
                httpContext.Response.Redirect(_missingTenantUrl, false);
                return;
            }
            await _next.Invoke(httpContext);
        }
    }
```

startup.cs

```
 public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.IHostingEnvironment env, MydbContext, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory){

 app.UseMiddleware<MissingDatabaseMiddleware>("/Setup/AppSetup");

 app.UseMvc(routes =>
            {
                routes.MapRoute(
                    name: "default",
                    template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
                routes.MapRoute(
                    name: "areas",
                    template: "{area:exists}/{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
            });

}
```

Answer (score 0):

the solution is to add a check in the request url

```
 public async Task Invoke(HttpContext httpContext, MemoryDbContext context)
        {
            if (!context.Database.CanConnect() && !httpContext.Request.GetEncodedUrl().Contains(_missingTenantUrl))
            {
                httpContext.Response.Redirect(_missingTenantUrl, false);
                return;
            }
            await _next.Invoke(httpContext);
        }
```